# How can i add custom css class to <ul> of AEM RTE component

Tags: class, html-lists, aem, rte

In RTE Component of AEM - unordered list by default provides "." bullet list.

I need to provide an option to make list with checkmark bullets.

If we add some style (by configuring styles nodes) for list, then markup is generating as below.

```
<ul>    
   <li>
      <span class="abc">Line One</span>
   </li>    
   <li>
      <span class="abc">Line Two</span>
   </li>    
</ul>
```

so whatever changes made( colored check mark or font) are applying to whole li content.

i need to insert a class in ul so that i can control default "." bullets behavior with some other list type.

on applying of style to ul div my source should look like

```
<ul class="abc">    
   <li>Line One</li>    
   <li>Line Two</li>    
</ul>
```

How can i achieve this in RTE.
is any custom list plugin changes required? or can we achieve by properties?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this to remove the default bullet points and add checkboxes.

```
<ul>
    <li><input type="checkbox"> Line One</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox"> Line Two</li>
 <ul>
```

The `type="checkbox"` turns your `<li>` items into a checkbox

```
ul {
    list-style-type:none;
}
```

and the `list-style-type:none;` property for  `<ul>` removes the default bullet points for your `<li>`

Comment: when you try adding some style in RTE component span tag gets added. Any style applies, then the markup would be like <li><span class="abc">Line One</span></li>. We cannot add this way and manually. I need some style class to be included in ul tag

Comment: There are some articles that talk about similar issues. Check this one out. https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2445863

Comment: This similar post helped me in implementation. https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2641433  and https://aemlab.blogspot.com/2019/07/aem-rte-custom-plugins-1.html Thank you.

Comment: You should update the question in case someone else comes looking for an answer. And you're welcome.